# iOS interface builder auto constraints problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, swift4

I currently trying to learn iOS development, however I’ve got stuck in interface builder. What I am trying to do is actually quite basic view. Unfortunately I feel pretty confused about „Less Than or Equal” relations. I thought that if a constraint is set as less than or equal, it will mean that it will have max size stetted in constant when there will be a plenty of space, otherwise it will be smaller. Turns out that no matter what, it always have the biggest size, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

On iPhone 11 interface looks like this:
[image: View on iPhone 11]

On iPhone 8 interface looks like this:
[image: View on iPhone 8]

For sure I don’t have all necessary knowledge about auto constraints right now, but maybe someone know where is a problem in this case? Also I would appreciate any good tutorials about interface builder or some good habits.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: “ I thought that if a constraint is set as less than or equal, it will mean that it will have max size stetted in constant when there will be a plenty of space, otherwise it will be smaller. ” To achieve that, you need two constraints: the inequality, and a lower priority “small” constraint to give the inequality something to aim at when the equality part cannot be satisfied.

Comment: However, it’s hard to help because you have not actually told us what layout you wish to achieve.

Comment: Hi matt,
I am trying to achieve the layout which will look on every device very similar to the look presented on the first screenshot (iPhone 11).

Comment: But what does that mean? A different phone may be shorter. So what exactly should happen? If you can’t tell me in words how can you tell the autolayout engine in constraints?

Comment: Hi,
Exactly, different phone may be shorter. So what I want, is to make the gaps between stack views smaller if the device has a smaller screen.
I am asking for a bit of understanding, I am just starting the adventure with ios.

Comment: Yes, so why do you have so many stack views? One stack view would do what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this seems to be the sort of thing you're after. Here it is on a 6s:

[image]

And here it is on an iPhone 11:

[image]

And here it is, for good measure, on the iPhone 6s *rotated*:

[image]

As you can see, there are four "groups" - the two labels, the label-and-text-field, the second label-and-text-field, and the button. They are *evenly distributed* from top to bottom on both screens.

That's the right idea, isn't it?

So how is that done? Simple. One vertical *stack view* filling the screen, with distribution set to Equal Spacing. Inside that, a UIView containing each group (except the button which is on its own), and each UIView given a fixed height by its own height constraint. There's a little more to it but that's the heart of the matter. Once you have that, you can tweak further as desired, of course.

Absolutely no code; the whole thing was configured in a few moments in Xcode's nib editor ("interface builder").

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create spacing between inputs based on the size of the device? I don't know if it will look like you expect, but I've had to do this before in different situations. You can use something like this  `NSLayoutConstraint` subclass to accommodate to accomplish what you want.  Essentially, depending on whether the constraint is vertical or horizontal, this class will calculate the screen size at runtime and modify the constraint size based on the percentage value you give it.

```swift
/// Layout constraint to calculate size based on multiplier.
class PercentLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var marginPercent: CGFloat = 0

    var screenSize: (width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
        return (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(layoutDidChange),
            name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    /**
     Re-calculate constant based on orientation and percentage.
     */
    func layoutDidChange() {
        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }

        switch firstAttribute {
        case .Top, .TopMargin, .Bottom, .BottomMargin:
            constant = screenSize.height * marginPercent
        case .Leading, .LeadingMargin, .Trailing, .TrailingMargin:
            constant = screenSize.width * marginPercent
        default: break
        }
    }

    deinit {
        guard marginPercent > 0 else { return }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

source: https://basememara.com/percentage-based-margin-using-autolayout-storyboard/